# HTTPConnection.request() & HTTPConnection.putrequest()

Tags: python, httplib

I need to use the python httplib.

And i code two sample, the first works, not the second.

But what i need is the second.

In the second sample, the data seems not be sent correctly.

I want to know where is the problem in the second.

TIA, Levi

Here is my two code:

first sample:

```
conn=httplib.HTTPConnection(data_host)
a_file=open("/home/levi/5","rb")
data=a_file.read()
a_file.close()
conn.request("PUT", "/webhdfs/v1/levi/5?op=CREATE&user.name=levi", data)
res=conn.getresponse()
print res.status,res.reason
print res.msg
conn.close()
```

And the second:

```
conn=httplib.HTTPConnection(data_host)
conn.connect()
conn.putrequest("PUT","/webhdfs/v1/levi/5?op=CREATE&user.name=levi")
conn.endheaders()
a_file=open("/home/levi/5","rb")
data=a_file.read()
a_file.close()
conn.send(data)
res=conn.getresponse()
print res.status,res.reason
print res.read()
print res.msg
conn.close()
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you sure that you can send request without headers?